# autocorrelation and ISI histogram of oscillatory neuron

Tags: signal-analysis

I'm trying to learn about different kinds of neurons and I got to a question that I'm stuck on: Given an oscillatory neuron that shoots poissonically for 50 ms and rests for 100ms:how it's autocorrelation looks like and how does it's isi ( ISI= distance between spikes)histogram looks like?

Comment: Why are you using the "matlab" tag? your question doesn't seem to be about matlab at all. In fact, is it a signal processing question, or a biology question?

Comment: I edited the question, I use matlab but I now understand that it's not mendatory.